# Matplotlib: How to set range of theta for a polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a polar contour plot with matplotlib. The data is only in the range of theta from 0 to 90 degree, but it always shows the whole range of 0 to 360 degree. So is there a way to set the range of theta to 0 to 90 degree?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid this is an open issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/328 .
Also other people have asked for this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/14711.

It would be definitely a nice feature and I wonder why it has not yet been implemented.